# Robotium (and Robotium Recorder) checking default application and location of test results

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, robotium, android-testing

I am doing a simple series of tests with Robotium Recorder on Android Studio.  I have created my test cases and had a few questions:

1. One of my tests is to click a URL link and to make sure that the default application dialogue/internet browser is displayed. I don't see an option to do this from the recorder (I wouldn't expect it). I have been looking through the [documentation for the solo object](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html) and do not see anything that would help me out. There has to be a way to check this.
2. Once a test is ran from Android Studio, where would the file containing the test results reside?

Comment: This has got to be an easy answer. Can nobody help?

Answer (score 0):

According to second question: I'm not sure that `Robotium` already creates any tests reports. You may use for it additional addons like `Spoon` or `Emma`.
Read: [Creating Test Reports for Android with Spoon and Emma](http://elekslabs.com/2014/05/creating-test-reports-for-android-with-spoon-and-emma.html)

I know also that `Robotium` can do a screenshots during the run of tests, but already I don't use this framework so please find on your own how to do it and where screenshots are placec if you feel a bit interesting.

Already, for creating instrumentation tests report I use `Gradle`. It generates quite good HTML reports. There are at least two ways to make it

- in `Android Studio`, on the left panel, choose `Gradle` then `app`, `verification`, finally `connectedAndroidTest`
- if you're familiar with Unix console go to your project location and just run the command:
  `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

NOTE: On the first time it might be needed to run before `chmod u+x gradlew`, if console would say that you don't have enough permissions to do it.

SUGGESTION: if you make one of your test failed, in generated by `Gradle` test report you would find a location of HTML generated tests report.

`Gradle test report` would look like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ElCEDWh_5JI/UFSuwkc_q7I/AAAAAAAAADk/rEU3HVTkaG8/s1600/Gradle+test+report.png) if all would run successful or [this](http://d2x79bjupkp9on.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/testfailure.png), if at least one would fail.